# Is DBPedia data contains the latest data? Is there another way to retrieve data

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I am new to DBPedia. I was trying to fetch data (Infobox details) from Wikipedia using SPARQL from DBPedia in C#. Using the below code:

```
SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpoint = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri("http://dbpedia.org/sparql"), "http://dbpedia.org");
string query = "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>" +
                   "PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>" +
                   "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>" +
                   "PREFIX  dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>" +
                   "SELECT ?numberOfEmployees WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/SomeOrganizationName> " +
                   "dbp:numberOfEmployees ?numberOfEmployees"}";
SparqlResultSet res = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet(query);
```

The data is not matching for some fields. Is there another way to retrieve data from DBPedia? I found https://live.dbpedia.org/sparql which I thought will be giving away fresh data but it does not return anything.

Comment: what is not matching on the public DBpedia endpoint? Please be more specific.

Comment: @UninformedUser For example the revenue or total number of employees in an organization. The data are not in sync with the wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if DBPedia is getting updated these days, WikiData https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page

might be a better resource to use

Comment: we have to distinguish between the DBpedia dataset and what is loaded into some public SPARQL endpoint. The DBpedia dataset itself is updated on a regularly basis: https://www.dbpedia.org/blog/dbpedia-snapshot-2022-09-release/ - those releases should also be loaded to the public endpoint a few days or weeks later afaik